# More than one paper-toast visible at same time

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Is there any way to have several paper-toasts stacked and visible at same time? I've tried to creat an ul with many li that contain each one a paper-toast and set the paper-toast.fitInto property to the parent li with no success

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (currentToast && currentToast !== this) {
       currentToast.close();
   }
```

This piece of code present inside the `paper-toast` element does not allow more than one toast to be opened at a time. So i don't think what you want is achievable with paper-toast

Comment: Thanks. I don't like very much this implementation. While I can understand  the reason to avoid several concurrent notification I don't like current flow, I'd prefer some logic to enqueue notifications. Closing the current one causes some notification not being shown